# How do you Facebook tag you and your friends in photos on an external website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

How do you Facebook tag you and your friends in photos on an external website?

This is an example of it in action, but not sure how they did it:

> http://mlb.mlb.com/photos/gigapan/?gpId=e9652024f103d4cd414e286ce041a419&c_id=tex

Basically I want people to be able to tag themselves and their Facebook friends in photos on my website.  Surely it must be possible since they did it here.  Any ideas how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is accomplished through the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

> At Facebook's core is the social graph; people and the connections
>   they have to everything they care about. The Graph API presents a
>   simple, consistent view of the Facebook social graph, uniformly
>   representing objects in the graph (e.g., people, photos, events, and
>   pages) and the connections between them (e.g., friend relationships,
>   shared content, and photo tags).

…

```
The connections supported for people and pages include:
Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...
Photo Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=...
Photo Albums: https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=...
Video Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos?access_token=...
```

…among others.

Comment: Thanks! Ahhh, so it's as easy as requesting a URL to retrieve a formatted list of results.  I still don't think you can actually "tag" yourself in external photos, but rather announce to your FB friends that you are in a specific photo.

Comment: I was fairly certain that you could, but a close reading of the API documentation seems to suggest that tagging someone in a photo might not be possible. I *is* possible, though, to @Tag someone as you would in a status update (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327353/tagging-friends-in-status-updates-from-facebook-api ) perhaps that's been extended to photos?